# Redirect to Dynamic URL only if that dynamic URL path name file not exist PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to redirect to dynamic URL only if that path name file not exist in my folders. How I can do this with .htaccess RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ product.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ results.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404   http://example.com/404.php
```

This rule is working, but with this my Images, CSS & JS files are not loading.

I want to redirect these dynamic URLs like http://example.com/abc/xyz to results.php and http://example.com/abc/xyz/tuv to product.php only if "abc/xyz" and "abc/xyz/tuv" not exist as files in my folder.

How we can do this.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rewritecond if file does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487061/rewritecond-if-file-does-not-exist)

Comment: _Aside:_ Your regex are rather ambiguous. What should happen to a request of the form `/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr`? And what about `/abc/def/`?

Comment: What form do your "Images, CSS & JS" URLs take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. This looks for if folder names mentioned by you are NOT existing in system as an actual directory/folder then rewrite them in backend to product.php(for abc/xyz/tuv) and to results.php(for abc/xyz) file.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^abc/xyz/tuv/?$ product.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^abc/xyz/?$ results.php [NC,L]
```